# Measuring websocket transfer rate

Tags: websocket, web-standards, web-performance

I am writing a frontend application that needs to know what is the current transfer rate with the server. When using HTTP, this is easy enough thanks to the [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance). You can access many measurement of the HTTP call by just using

```
performance.getEntriesByName(url);
```

However it seems WebSockets are not covered by this API. So I have been trying to find a way to do the same without it.

It seems the [MessageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) has a [timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp) which indicates the time at which the event is created. However, there isn't much documentation about when that MessageEvent is created. Is it at the reception of the first byte (which I hope) or is it once the whole message is downloaded (which is probably the case). Does anyone happen to know if there is more detail on how WebSockets messages are managed by browser?

More generally, how do you measure your WebSockets transfer rate from the frontend without server side help?